# String Theory- Are strings the end? What are they made of?

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory

Although I have informed myself in string theory through reading books and watching videos, I do not know or understand what superstrings are made of. History has definitely shown us that when we think something is fundemental, there is always something smaller.

What are superstrings made of?
Can we go smaller than strings?

Comment: Why everyone asks this question an no one asks what elementary particles are made of?

Comment: @MBN: I guess they think it's settled that they are made of strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46573/2451

Comment: I think that a theory, before to be considered  the fundamental theory should be corroborated   by some experimental evidence, as it happened for  quantum mechanics, relativity (special and general) and QFT.