# What is the most fundamental peice of matter? What is it that thing which can no more be sub-divided?

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, elementary-particles

I know that there is theory that strings are the most fundamental particles. But if it is a string, then it can be 'cut' into pieces, and if it can be 'cut', then it can be cut at infinitely many places. Then does this makes the strings fundamental? If not, then what is ultimately *the* fundamental piece of matter?

Comment: With classical thinking, you can't comprehend what subatomic particles are. They aren't something you can cut. Can you imagine how an atom can exist at two places at once?

Comment: In QFT, they are excitation of matter field. This is most modern solid concept (String Theory is still fictional). Now, think of dividing excitation of matter field.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46573/2451) Phys.SE post. You may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41676/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.

Comment: If atoms can exist at two places at the same time,and if this is true to the word,then i think that this fact can also be explained intuitively.I think that intuition is a tricky game, because there is no L.H.S and no R.H.S. Therefore making mistake is easy.But through my own experience i have realized how intuition and imagination can bring out results that are surprising.I think if subatomic particles behave oddly,this is a good sign for science students.Well,thank you for your response, Mr. Shekhar.On one think i agree with you though.Classical picture and 'cutting' are not the right words.