# What produces String tension in Strings theory?

Tags: string-theory

In (classical) physics, **tension** describes the pulling force exerted by each end of a string, which is a one-dimensional **continuous** object, At the atomic level, tension is produced when atoms or molecules are pulled apart from each other and gain electromagnetic potential energy.

But there is **no** atomic level for strings of strings theory, so

What produces [string tension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tension_%28physics%29#Strings_in_modern_physics) in [Strings theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory)?

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46573/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 4):

Right now, when people talk of string theory, strings are the fundamental objects -- they aren't made up of anything. So they have an intrinsic property of energy, and energy per unit length corresponds to the string's tension.