# In string theory, is it fair to say that strings are actually "fundamental units of information"?

Tags: string-theory, spacetime, relativity

I'm new to the stack, and came here after researching this thread:

[What are the strings in string theory made of?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46573/what-are-the-strings-in-string-theory-made-of?newreg=906fa8258a8b4f64b9dfa800ca675bbc)

Apparently I can't comment there yet, so I am simply asking this question in a different form. I know that a number of physicists have come to believe that the fundamental component of all things is not some kind of "stuff", but units of information. Is that what strings are meant to describe? Fundamental units of information.

Also, what is the relationship between strings and space? Are strings fundamental units of space? Or are they the product of space oscillating? Or are the two inseparable? Maybe these should be posed as separate questions, I don't quite know the proper format here, but any answers would be welcome.

Comment: @CountTo10  in a string model, the electron is a specific excitation of a string.

Comment: @annav. I worded it very badly Anna,  I was trying to be balancd over a contentious issue. I am leaving this, far too addictive ,but otherwise terrific site. Thank you for all your answers, both directly to my questions  and others. I know a lot more about how subtle physics can be now. Regards

Comment: I do not have time to write this today, but strings are related to units of information theory or quantum information. I will try to carve out a period of time to write on this tomorrow.